# Ugly fractions including exponents in superscript

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, fractions

Consider typesetting the following expression in LaTeX:

```
\[
a^{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\lambda x}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{\lambda x}}}
\]
```

The output is as follows: [image]

This looks quite ugly. I think the issue is that the superscripts in the fraction are the same size as Euler's constant in the same expression, when they would look a lot nicer if they were smaller. Also, I think the expression would be more aesthetically pleasing if the entire fraction was raised vertically ever so slightly. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: A suggested (typographically) solution is something like: `\[
a^{\beta/(1-\beta)}\text{ where }\beta=e^{\lambda x}
\]`

Comment: By default at 10pt text size math uses 10pt, 7pt and 5pt you are already at the smallest scriptscriptsize (5pt) for the e, if you made the \lambda x smaller some of your readers (including this one) won't be able to read it (on paper) pdf of course you can zoom in...

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest that you replace `\frac` notation with inline-fraction notation. Optionally, write `\exp(...)` instead of `e^{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
a^{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\lambda x}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{\lambda x}}}
\quad
a^{\mathrm{e}^{\lambda x}/(1-\mathrm{e}^{\lambda x})}
\quad
a^{\exp(\lambda x)/(1-\exp(\lambda x))}
\]
\end{document}
```